# wic image is EFI but need legacy

Tags: yocto, yocto-wic

I added meta-intel layer to build a hardware image.

After build ( bitbake xxxxxx ) I got output:

```
core-image-minimal-genericx86-64.wic
```

I dd copy this file to a USB, it can boot and login to yocto.

but it is EFI mode.

How to generate image to legacy mode?

Another problem, I found some machines can't boot ( no GRUB screen ) the same disk but some machines can.

Is it because the BIOS problem?

Answer (score 1):

In [this accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622887/2573334) they mention:

> **By default meta-intel .wic images only have an EFI bootloader**, and
> will not boot via legacy BIOS.
>
> An hddimg will have both an EFI bootloader and the syslinux binaries
> that let it boot from **legacy BIOS**.

So I guess one solution is to build an `hddimage`. Just change it in

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "wic"
```

for the one you need.

### Update: use wic create

There is a much better and flexible solution by using the power of wic.

On your bash env, where you did **execute bitbake** call  `wic list images`:

```bash
$ wic list images
  generic-bootdisk              
  grub-bootdisk-microcode                       Create an EFI disk image with grub-efi
  ...
  (lots)
  ...
```

I'll give you lots of images, then you can covert the `.wic` to any of those like this:

```
#
# wic create <type> -e <image>
#
$ wic create grub-bootdisk-microcode -e my-image
..
... will create the desired image and some instructions
... on the current path
...
$
```

You need to be on the environment, and the image is your image already created by bitbake.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but hopefully it would help someone else.

Instead of using an hddimg, you can use a custom wks file and use the "bootimg-pcbios" source option.

In your local.conf

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "wic"
WKS_FILE = "custom.wks"
```

In custom.wks

```
part /boot --source bootimg-pcbios --ondisk sda --label boot --active --align 1024 --use-uuid
```